# Please help me with some CSS issues

Tags: css, menu

I am currently customizing the header of the RWD theme.

1. I cant get the cart pop-out to show
2. The pop-out sub menu wont stretch 100%

[www.sssextreme.com](http://www.sssextreme.com) Is my website url.

Comment: can you show your `header.phtml` file?

Comment: Hi there its to long for me to send on stack exchange, I have not changed any settings in this file from magentos default one

Answer (score 1):

This is not a Magento specific question, so it will probably get put on hold, but for 2:

```
#custommenu {
    position: initial;
}
```